# Change Nuxt.js SPA mode to Universal mode

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, nuxt.js

I've chosen SPA mode when I first created the project, but after a while I want to change it to Universal mode. Is it possible to change it from `nuxt.config.js`?

Answer (score 3):

For the ones who receive the deprecation warning now instead of using `mode: "universal"`
You have to do the next in your `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
    ssr: true,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can easily change it on your `nuxt.config.js` file by change `mode:'spa'` to `mode:'universal'`. Here is [the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode/).

Also remember after you do this if your server is running you need to stop and re-run it again.